# 1064 sql error in create table statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam getting the error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID' int, 'MGR_ID' int, 'DEPT_ID' int, 'NAME' VARCHAR2(30), 'SAL' int, ' at line 3 while creating a table. I have already a table department with PK as 'dept_id'. Help lease

CREATE TABLE emp
(
'ID' int, 
'MGR_ID' int, 
'DEPT_ID' int, 
'NAME' VARCHAR2(30), 
'SAL' int, 
'DOJ' DATE, 
 PRIMARY KEY ('ID') , 
 FOREIGN KEY ('MGR_ID') REFERENCES emp('ID') , 
 FOREIGN KEY ('DEPT_ID') REFERENCES department('dept_id') 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back ticks ( ` ) to define object names, but not single quotes ( ' ).

Your table definition shall be:

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
    `ID` int, 
    `MGR_ID` int, 
    `DEPT_ID` int, 
    `NAME` VARCHAR2(30), 
    `SAL` int, 
    `DOJ` DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) , 
     FOREIGN KEY (`MGR_ID`) REFERENCES emp(`ID`) , 
     FOREIGN KEY (`DEPT_ID`) REFERENCES department(`dept_id`) 
)
```

Comment: I used this one, but not working

Comment: `Varchar2` wont work in MySQL. Change it to `Varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote your field names with `'`. That turns them into strings, not field names.

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
   id int,
   mgr_id int, 
   etc...
);
```

If you **DO** need to quote a field name because it's a reserved word, you use backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
   `desc` int <---"desc" is a reserved word
   etc...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   CREATE TABLE emp
 (
  `ID` int (20), 
  `MGR_ID` int (20), 
  `DEPT_ID` int (20), 
  `NAME` VARCHAR (30), 
  `SAL` int (20), 
  `DOJ` DATE, 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID) , 
   FOREIGN KEY (MGR_ID) REFERENCES emp(ID) , 
   FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID) REFERENCES department(dept_id) 
   )
```

Comment: tried but no success, same error.

Comment: post this error please. its not same

Comment: you may give the length of your integers , look my updated answer now.